# Mongodb ordering results by multiple fields in $group stage

Tags: mongodb

I need to perform a similar task as mentioned in the below SQL query but in mongodb. Below is the SQL query:

> last_value(status) over (partition by entity_entry_id order by
> entity_id, entity_ingest_date)

As can be seen, I am partitioning the data by check_in_able_id and ordering the partitioned results by two fields and then selecting the last value in each partition.

How can I perform the same task in mongodb? I wrote the below query:

```
 db.products.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        status_id: "$STATUS_ID"
      },
      last_entity_status: {
        $last: "$ENTITY_ID, $ENTITY_INGEST_DATE"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

but the above query doesn't work as $last takes only one parameter,

Comment: can you share some sample data?

Comment: You can use multiple `$last` parameters - if there are multiple values you are trying to get.

Comment: How will define the sort order if I use multiple $last statements? I am trying to get the same value but I am trying to sort it using 2 fields and then get the last value out of that sort order by 2 fields as I mentioned in the SQL query above.

Comment: @varman Can't share the sample data here. Below is the use case as can be solved with the SQL query I shared above.

There is a timeseries database and because of timeseries nature, there are multiple values against the same column on which I am grouping. While grouping, I need to sort on other two fields and then fetch the data point which should be the last value in that sort order.

Comment: $sort first, then $group and take the $last.